# "Получим обратную связь" или "получим обратной связи"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

*Будем очень признательны если получим обратную связь от Вас* или *обратной связи от Вас*?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку выражение утвердительное, то правильно "**получим обратную связь**" (*винительный* падеж). В случае же глагола с отрицанием возможны оба варианта. Вариант с *родительным* падежом:

> Мы пока **не** получаем обратн**ой** связ**и** от вас.

Comment: Может быть, достаточно написать "получим обратную связь" и всё? Зачем добавлять "от вас". Не будет ли это тавтологией? Ведь и так понятно, от кого она.

Comment: "Обратная связь" - наразлагаемый кибернетический термин, он не означает "мы с вами связались, теперь давайте вы с нами". По смыслу это ответная реакция на какое-либо воздействие, которая может исходить как от адресата, так и из иного, известного адресату источника, поэтому тавтологии здесь нет.

Comment: Вообще-то это выражение, используемое в официально -деловом стиле речи (если уж речь идёт о русском языке)1
Реферат: Устно-речевая деловая коммуникация
BestReferat.ru›referat-100615.html
Официально-деловая коммуникация. Официально-деловой стиль речи обусловлен практическими требованиями жизни и профессиональной деятельности.
2
Оф-Дел. письменная речь. Учебник
StudFiles.ru›preview/3171495/
FAQ Обратная связь Вопросы и предложения. Вузы. Предметы. ... Формирование русской официально-деловой письменной речи. ...

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Будем очень признательны,  если получим обратную связь от Вас **(В.п.).**

Сравнить: **Получить** обратную связь **(В.п.)** ― **получение** обратной связи **(Р.п.).**

Пример: Будем очень признательны за получение обратной связи от Вас.

Answer (score 0):

**Будем очень признательны, если получим обратную связь от Вас.**

Перед "если" ставится запятая.

Обра́тная связь (англ. feedback — «обратная подача») — в широком смысле означает отзыв, отклик, ответную реакцию на какое-либо действие или событие.(Википедия). Это выражение используется в официально-деловом стиле речи именно в сочетаниях "обратная связь **от кого-то**". Так что сомнения о наличии тавтологии отпадают.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал `Будем очень признательны, если получим от Вас отклик по обратной связи` (или даже конкретнее - `отклик через форму обратной связи`, если таковая форма есть). Я понимаю, что feedback - это существительное, но на русском языке "получить [обратную] связь" совершенно не звучит. Можно получить что-то *по* связи. Говорить об обратной связи как о вещи в себе уместно разве что в очень обощённом смысле (`Согласно обратной связи, посетители испытывали трудности с разделом "Вопросы и ответы"`).

Answer (score 0):

Тут просто вопрос падежа. Если задать

> Получим чего? 
>   Ответ - связи

А если задать вопрос

> Получим что?
>   Ответ - связь

Правильно поставить винительный падеж, то есть второй вариант. Обратную связь.